# Good books on high availability database?

Tags: sql-server, database, high-availability

My thesis at university is studying about high availability database. Can you suggest me some good books on this field? I want to concentrate on SQL Server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Gray and Reuter's [Transaction Processing: Concepts and Techniques](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558601902) is quite a good book on the underlying theory.  It has quite a lot of background reading on fault tolerance (one of the authors used to work for Tandem) and other related items.  Fairly dry and textbook-ish, but arguably the definitive work on the subject.

For material specific to SQL server, the [Guru's Guide books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321287509), or [SQL Server Internals](http://www.sqlserverinternals.com/) are a good start.

Answer (score 3):

Allan Hirt is a notable person in SQL Server area specializing in High Availability and wrote an excellent book on this topic.

[http://www.amazon.com/Server-2005-High-Availability-ebook/dp/B001U5VK08/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1261964956&sr=8-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001U5VK08)

SQLPass.Org is a free website and you can find few videos from industry experts on this topic as well.

http://www.sqlpass.org/LearningCenter/SummitOnDemand.aspx

Paul Randal managed SQL Server team and he has some excellent posts on this topic as well.
http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/High-Availability.aspx

And finally few good white papers on this topic at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee229552(SQL.10).aspx

Comment: I have most of Allan Hirt's books... very good stuff.  The one you referenced for SQL 2005 as well as this one http://www.amazon.com/Server-Failover-Clustering-Experts-Voice/dp/1430219661/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1262643952&sr=1-1 are staples on my desk at the office.